# How to automate check for multiple website time taken to load from excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have around 100 websites in an excel for which i need to check the time taken for website to load. 
Currently I am manually doing it in Internet Explorer by using developer tool(F12)*> Network*> Taken(Column) one by one. 
Is there any way to do this check automatically??

Comment: No build in solution by default. But you could write some code in VBA or look for an add in to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your level of VBA, and this is far from perfect, but as a starting point this is a code I normally use to scrape websites, but I have modified slightly to time how long it takes each website to open. This assumes you have all your websites in column `A`, it will print the time taken to open a website in column `B`. Bare in mind this is timing the time the macro takes to run per website, so not entirely accurate to how long the actual site takes to load.

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub ImportWebsiteDate()
'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, WDApp As Object, staTime As Double, elapsedTime As Double

'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument, websiteNo As Integer, curSite As String
    websiteNo = Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row
'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

For i = 1 To websiteNo
    curSite = Cells(i, 1).Value
    ie.Visible = False
    staTime = Timer
    ie.navigate curSite

    'Wait until IE is done loading page
    Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to " & curSite
    DoEvents
    Loop
    elapsedTime = Round(Timer - staTime, 2)
    Cells(i, 2).Value = elapsedTime
Next i
Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

This won't just work if you copy and paste, read [this site](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm) for info on referencing the required applications.

Comment: Just realised I started the timer in the wrong place, code has been amended,